# Find the top 10 centre most values from each clusters done by k-means using python

Tags: python, machine-learning, cluster-analysis, k-means

I have a data frame and I have clustered it into 3 clusters using k-means clustering.

Now I want to find the top 10 centre most values from each clusters.

How to do it using python ?

Comment: We need to see some code, be told about libraries you are using, etc...

Answer (score 2):

So, after finding 3 clusters mean you have 3 centroids, which are nothing but 3 
datapoints or

vectors of size -> number of inputs right?

so, you also have data points of dataset segregated to their cluster number. For 10 closest points of cluster1, find the distance between points in cluster1 and centroid1.And sort them in decreasing order of distance and extract top 10 points.

Similarly for all 3 clusters.

Example:

```
centroid1 : (1,2)
points in cluster 1: (2,3) (4,5) (1,1) (2,0) (3,4)
```

top2 points are : `(1,1) (2,3).`
based on their distances.